# Can the JDBC Kafka Connector pull data from multiple databases?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I would love to setup a cluster of JDBC Kafka Connectors and configure them to pull from multiple databases running on the same host.

I've been looking through the Kafka Connect documentation, and it appears that after you configure the JDBC connector that it can only pull data from a single database.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the mode you start your workers (standalone or distributed) :

**In the standalone mode**, you can start multiple jdbc connectors by using :

```
bin/connect-standalone worker.properties connector1.properties [connector2.properties connector3.properties ...]
```

Where each connector.properties match one database.

More details here : [Running workers](http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/connect/userguide.html#running-workers)

**In the distributed mode**, first start workers with :

```
 bin/connect-distributed worker.properties
```

Then push each configuration with POST http requests like :

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "jdbc-source", "config": {"connector.class":"JdbcSourceConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "connection.url":"jdbc:sqlite:test.db", "topic.prefix":"connect-jdbc-test-", "mode":"bulk" }}' http://worker_host:8083/connectors
```

Or, to use a file containing the JSON-formatted configuration

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @config.json http://worker_host:8083/connectors
```